# itunes connect - beta entitlement missing error

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval, provisioning-profile, testflight

I create a new App Store Distribution profile containing the beta entitlement to distribute builds via TestFlight, I create my application based on new profile that was contain beta entitlement, when I submit my application I got this error:

> Generate a new App Store Distribution profile containing the beta
>   entitlement to distribute builds via TestFlight

Here is my provision profile:

```
<key>Entitlements</key>
<dict>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>XXXXXXX.*</string>
    </array>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>XXXXXXX.my.companyname.test</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
    <string>XXXXXXX</string>
    <key>beta-reports-active</key>
    <true/>

</dict>
```

I have "beta-reports-active" in my build, I do not know why I got this error I regenerate everything, does apple change/add something to the submission process/test-flight after 1 February without announcement?

Does anyone knows what is the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: My guess is that although you've got that profile, it's not the one that the build system is _using_. It might help to delete any old distribution profiles for this app, both from Member Center and from Xcode. Controlling which profile is used is not so easy as it used to be... It's kind of hit and miss...

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the comment but I checked the .iPA file and it contains the correct profile, if the old uploaded app doesn't conation the beta entitlement then can I update it with the version that contains beta entitlement ?(my guess is yes)

Comment: You're using an IPA file? So you're uploading with Application Loader? Do you get a better result if you just select the archive and click Submit?

Comment: Yes I am using APplication loader it is for my client and it should submitted base on application loader I cannot submitted it via xcode

Comment: I am having this very problem. I have confirmed that my IPA's `embedded.mobileprovision` file contains the `beta-reports-active` flag set to true, yet when I upload the .ipa it complains "To use TestFlight Beta Testing, build 113 must contain the correct beta entitlement." and shows a warning icon beside the build. Did you manage to make any headway on this??

Comment: Nevermind I found the answer! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28998478/apple-testflight-upload-warning-itms-90191-missing-beta-reports-active-entitl

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by additionally adding the `beta-reports-active` key to my Target's `Entitlements.plist` file in the Xcode project.

[Apple TestFlight upload warning ITMS-90191: missing `beta-reports-active` entitlement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28998478/apple-testflight-upload-warning-itms-90191-missing-beta-reports-active-entitl)

The `beta-reports-active` key must be added to the Provisioning Profile **AND** to the Target's entitlements.

`TargetName.entitlements`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>

    // ...

    <key>beta-reports-active</key>
    <true/>

    // ...

</dict>
</plist>
```

After adding the entitlement to my Target, I'm able to successfully upload the build to iTunes Connect TestFlight without the `ITMS-90191` warning:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **Xcode 9** and **Swift 4**

I also faced same issue when I try to create ipa file for my swift project. I search a lot but could not find any good solution. But finally my senior helped me same way as pkamb said in his comment, adding key "**beta-reports-active**" in your projectName.entitlements file will solve your problem. Open projectName.entitlements file as source code and edit it as follows.

My projectName.entitlements file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>beta-reports-active</key>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I just added key :- **beta-reports-active** as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 10: you must not add the `beta-reports-active` manually to entitlements if you want to use Xcode automatic signing.