# Why the Missing 64-bit support happened when upload to the iTunes connect?

Tags: ios, xcode, arm64

I try to upload the file via Application Loader. But I got the mail from iTunes store.

**Missing 64-bit support** - Beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK. Beginning June 1, 2015 app updates will also need to follow the same requirements. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code.

But I already add the arm64 in Xcode like the following picture.

[image]

**Why the Missing 64-bit support happened when upload to the iTunes connect ?**

Did I missing something ?

Comment: Looks like it should be good to me, did you somehow not send a release build... Like maybe archive is set to use a debug setting?

Comment: I'm wondering whether, when Apple threw this switch on Feb 1, they messed something up. Look at this unrelated question where the questioner is getting pushback from iTunes Connect about lack of an entitlement he knows is there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311311/itunes-connect-beta-entitlement-missing-error

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had same problem today I set Build Active Architecture to NO and it got submitted. Give a try

Comment: But he _has_ Build Active Architecture set to NO - for a release build, which is what he should be making when he archives.

Comment: Yea you are right I had same problem in my case I had both Yes I made them no it worked

Comment: I also disconnect the iPhone and make the top bar is in "iOS Device". It is working.

Answer (score 16):

From this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26796934/451475) and this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26801060/451475)

- Architecture: "Standard architectures" arm7, arm64
- Valid Architectures: "arm64" , armv7...
- Build Active Architecture Only - NO (specially... if your connected device is not arm64 compatible)

Comment: Just to add, You can set "Build Active Architecture Only" No for Release Build, And Yes for Debug Build

Comment: The above settings worked for me, but I had to change them in both Project, Target (and also Pods  for those using cocoapods)

Answer (score 5):

Most commonly happens when I archive *while* a device is connected (as it affect the architecture).

*(As mentioned in a comment by Martin to Shashi3456643's answer)*

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue with Xamarin.ios deployment. Later found that it was third party library causing the issue. I have maps in my app using from Arc GIS. I updated my dll to latest provided and resolved my issue.