# Missing 64-bit support

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, 64-bit

Xcode 6.1, Phonegap project, Validation passes without any issue, still after submitting for review I get an email stating that my binaries are invalid since they are missing the 64-bit support.

I've configured my build as suggested in :: [Why the Missing 64-bit support happened when upload to the iTunes connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312779/why-the-missing-64-bit-support-happened-when-upload-to-the-itunes-connect)

After submission for review, I get this message in the mail:

> **Missing 64-bit support** - Beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps
>   submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built
>   with the iOS 8 SDK. Beginning June 1, 2015 app updates will also need
>   to follow the same requirements. To enable 64-bit in your project, we
>   recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard
>   architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit
>   code.

I even tried disconnecting the device I had.. but to no avail.

help, please...

Comment: Have you done it for both debug and release? How about a screen shot (with expanded sections) of the relevant areas of your Build Settings?

Comment: yes, I have. 
regretfully i was not able to upload screenshots (not enough reputation points apparently)

Comment: Could you upload it to some image hosting site? http://postimage.org seems to be such a site as far as I can see.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/g1g9wukcp/

Comment: Forgive me, as my knowledge of PhoneGap stuff is non existent, but what do you create them in? What was that a screen shot of as it didn't look like Xcode. The error also says "and be built with the iOS 8 SDK" Are you doing that?

Comment: the image capture is form xcode.  phonegap creates an xcode project and from that point on, the build and deployment is in xcode. i configured the sdk root to work with ios 8 sdk.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a)

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/4j8zuqk95/

Comment: I have never seen it played out the way you have, so I find that odd. What Base SDK setting do you have?

Comment: I've set the exact same configuration to the project and target on both the main project (dadaviz) and the internal one (cordova == phonegap)

Comment: root sdk(?) is set to: Latest iOS (iOS 8.1)

Comment: Sorry, I'm at a loss then. Good luck finding a solution.

Comment: From image your are posted, your project settings are correct.
Seems you are using 3rd party, libraries or frameworks, which are not build for 64 bit. Which libs/frameworks your project use?

Comment: cordova ios libraries. I've made the same settings there and ran it on an iphone 6 device just to make sure it can run 64bit (I hope thats the case).