# App not compatible on iPhone 4s and 5 in Testflight

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight

I'm nearly finished with my app, and I'm [testflighting](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) it right now. The problem is that I can't get it to work on iPhone 4s and iPhone 5. The deployment target is set to 8.0, and it's running perfectly on the iPhone 4s simulator. When my testers open TestFlight, they can see this list of compatible devices, and people with devices older than iPhone 5s can't install it. This is what my testers see in TestFlight:

[image]

Another strange thing is that it compatible with iPad, but I've set my devices to iPhone only in Xcode.

I have tried researching this, but I can only find questions related to auto layout and sizing issues. I've made sure everything should look fine on all devices, what am I missing?

Comment: FYI - iPhone-only apps can be run on iPads. You can't prevent this.

Comment: Looks like you may have only support the arm64 processor. Be sure to include arm7/arm7s to support the older iPhones and iPads.

Comment: @rmaddy My architecture is set to include arm7/arm7s under Build settings. BUT.. "Build Active Architecture Only" was set to "Yes", and according to [this (link)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312779/why-the-missing-64-bit-support-happened-when-upload-to-the-itunes-connect), it should be set to "No". I'm trying that out, and updating the question if that was the solution.

Comment: The "Build Active Architecture Only" should only be Yes for debug builds, not release or archive builds.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem was a pretty easy one to solve, thanks to rmaddy for pointing it out. I had to set **Built Active Architecture Only** in Build settings to **No** for release. I didn't change the setting for debug as that only gave me compilation errors. 
See screenshot:

[image].

Comment: This Answer is not solving the problem

Comment: @NazishAli this solved my problem at least, but it may be something different in your case. When i set Built Active Architecture Only to No and republished to testflight, it said compatible with all devices > iOS 8.0