# App not compatible on iPhone 5 in App Store

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I've just released my app on App Store through iTunes Connect. The point is that I cannot get it to run on iPhone 5 and older.

This is what I get on app information section:

[image]

I have tried researching this, but I can only find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33900295/app-not-compatible-on-iphone-4s-and-5-in-testflight) about nearly the same problem in a test environment. Is this the solution also to my problem? Am I missing something?

Furthermore, why is it showing iPad compatibility when I just uploaded iPhone screenshots?

Thanks for your support

Comment: 1. "Is this the solution also to my problem?" probably implies that you haven't tested whether the solution listed also solves your problem. I would suggest you try first, taking note of all the build configurations.

2. iPad compatibility is shown because iPhone apps run on the iPad.

Comment: All iPhone apps can be installed in used on the iPad, only if they require cellular moden will they not be available on the iPad. It looks like your app is 64 bit only therefor it is not available for iPhone 5(c) and 4S

Comment: According to app release guidelines, app must run on both iPad and iPhone. That's why it is showing iPAD compatibility. Second, you must test your app on iPhone 5, iPhone 5s, all other compatible devices.

Comment: @StevePalmer You're right, I haven't test it as I'm not the developer but I still wanted to gather some insights on the topic. Sorry for that and thanks for your answer.