# Apple TestFlight upload warning ITMS-90191: missing `beta-reports-active` entitlement

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

When I upload a build to the new Apple owned and iTunes Connect-integrated TestFlight, I see the following log:

> WARNING ITMS-90191: "Missing beta entitlement. Your app does not include the beta-reports-active entitlement. If you intend to distribute this build via TestFlight for beta testing, please re-build this app with a newly generated provisioning profile."

When I look at the build on iTunes Connect, I also see the following warning:

[image: To use TestFlight Beta Testing, build X.Y.Z must contain the correct beta entitlement. For more information, see the FAQ.]

> To use TestFlight Beta Testing, build X.Y.Z must contain the correct beta entitlement. For more information, see the FAQ.

The linked FAQ states:

> #### What should I do if my prerelease build does not contain the correct beta entitlement?
>
> To use the TestFlight app to test your prerelease build, it must be signed with an App Store Distribution Provisioning profile that includes the beta entitlement. New Distribution Provisioning profiles generated in the iOS Developer Center will automatically contain the beta entitlement.
>
> If you have an existing Distribution Provisioning Profile that was generated before the launch of TestFlight Beta Testing, you must regenerate the profile.

The problem is that I *am* using a newly created App Store Distribution Provisioning Profile. I created it like so:

[image: App Store Distribution Provisioning Profile]

When I inspect the source of the downloaded Provisioning Profile, I see:

```
<key>Entitlements</key>
<dict>
    // ...
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>production</string>
    <key>beta-reports-active</key>
    <true/>
    // ...
```

So the Provisioning Profile is set for `production` and **does** contain the `beta-reports-active` entitlement.

However, iTunes Connect continues to complain when this build is uploaded to TestFlight.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue? Is this an Apple bug?

rdar://20128048

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First, be sure that you are using an **App Store Distribution Provisioning Profile**. This is likely a **different** provisioning profile from the Ad Hoc Distribution Provisioning Profile you were using to sign pre-Apple TestFlight builds.

I continued to hit Error ITMS-90191 *after* I switched to an App Store Distribution Provisioning Profile. I fixed the issue by additionally adding the `beta-reports-active` key to my Target's `Entitlements.plist` file in the Xcode project.

The `beta-reports-active` key must be included in the Provisioning Profile **AND** the Target's entitlements.

`TargetName.entitlements`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>

    // ...

    <key>beta-reports-active</key>
    <true/>

    // ...

</dict>
</plist>
```

After adding the entitlement to my Target, I'm able to successfully upload the build to iTunes Connect TestFlight without the `ITMS-90191` warning:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Thats it. But I had to create a new provisioning profile, altough the existing one had the described key.

Answer (score 2):

Manually editing the plist file didn't do it for me.
Editing an existing profile and generating the file also did NOT work this time.
But, just like for joehl, creating a brand NEW provision profile actually fixed it for me. So, create an all new Provision Profile and and you will be back in business.  This looks like a glitch in TestFlight.

Comment: Was your "old" provisioning profile an App Store Distribution provisioning profile? The new Apple TestFlight does definitely require a different provisioning profile type than the old TestFlight.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by adding this to my xcodebuild script.

```
xcodebuild ... PROVISIONING_PROFILE=<Provisioning Profile Id>
```

Looks like setting **Code Sign Identities** in **Build Settings** manually could fix this problem too.

Answer (score 2):

Using an AppStore provisioning profile solved this for me. I managed to successfully distribute and install on devices. I was using an AdHoc provisioning profile as usual and suddenly I started to get this error. Frustrating stuff indeed.

Answer (score 2):

I edited my `entitlements.plist` with the following command:

`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :beta-reports-active bool true" entitlements.plist`

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution: Delete your previous provisioning profile, and create a new one. solves my problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Fastlane, make sure you set ad-hoc to false for the `sigh`  step, otherwise it will generate an ad-hoc profile which is not suitable for TestFlight distribution. i.e.:

```
sigh(
  adhoc: false,
  team_id: "XXXXXXXXX"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just successfully submitted a new app version to TestFlight and realized after Apple accepted my submission that I did not have beta-reports-active in my Entitlements.plist.

In my previous version submissions for TestFlight, my submission would have been rejected for the "Missing beta entitlement"

Has anyone else noticed that the beta-reports-active is no longer required for TestFlight?