# Missing Beta Entitlement iTunes Connect "error" - Xamarin Forms PCL

Tags: ios, xamarin, app-store-connect, beta

I have a problem, I have the same project in Xamarin on visual studio 2017.
When I deploy transmission certificates and load it all on itunes connect through Application Loader.

The problem is that, with one of the two applications (
I change the certificate every time I release an app or another.), I can not make the release for beta testers.
As you can see in the image below:

[image]

With the first App all goes well, but when the second load gives me the error that you see when you try to release it with testflight: Missing Beta Entitlement.

I looked online and I tried to put in info.plist file the following string:

> ```
>   <key>beta-reports-active</key>  <true/>
> ```

But without success. Can anyone advise me how to solve? Thank you.
I uploaded to connect itunes version 1.13 but I get the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I recommend here is to clean/clear your provisioning profile from [Apple Developer Website](https://developer.apple.com/).

Are you letting Xcode manage code signing identity ?
If so then it will create provisioning profile for you when you will be building for Release.

Indeed, it happens to me, it was a terrible mess in my configuration on Apple Developer.

I just removed everything, provisioning profile, create 1 Development and 1 Production certificate.

Then when you build for Release, Xcode will create provisioning profile for you, it starts with "XC".

Your issue is

> likely a different provisioning profile from the Ad Hoc Distribution
>   Provisioning Profile you were probably using to sign TestFlight builds

TBH changing certificate evertytime you release an app or an other might also create a mess in Xcode configuration.

[Helpful Post Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28998478/apple-testflight-upload-warning-itms-90191-missing-beta-reports-active-entitl)

Comment: After some test..I've solved, I delete all Certificates and recreate only one AppStore Distribution. Now Works. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution :)